# JSON data not showing up on UITableView

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire for parsing JSON and I retrieve the correct JSON result on console, but it's not showing up on UITableView. I think it's race condition, but I don't see how to fix it.

WeatherViewController.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class WeatherViewController: UITableViewController{

    var weatherStore: WeatherStore!
    var weather: Weather!


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(weatherStore.allWeathers.count)
        return weatherStore.allWeathers.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let weather = weatherStore.allWeathers[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = String(weather.id)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = weather.main

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        weatherStore.createWeather { (fetchedWeather: Weather) in
            self.weatherStore.allWeather.append(fetchedWeather)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
        let statusNarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height

        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: statusNarHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        tableView.contentInset = insets
        tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

WeatherStore.swift

Edit: I commented out afterWeatherCreated(newWeather!) because after Harshai comment I see that I don´t need it there.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire


    class WeatherStore {


        var allWeather = [Weather]()


        func createWeather(afterWeatherCreated: (Weather) -> Void) { 
            var id: Int = 9
            var main: String = ""
            var newWeather: Weather?
            Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?xyz")
                .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        // id = JSON["id"] as! Int
                        //main = JSON["main"] as! String
                        let dataArray: NSArray = JSON["weather"] as! NSArray

                        for item in dataArray { 
                            let obj = item as! NSDictionary
                            for (key, value) in obj {
                                if key.isEqual("id"){
                                    id = value as! Int
                                }
                                if key.isEqual("main"){
                                    main = value as! String
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    newWeather = Weather(id: id, main: main)
                    //afterWeatherCreated(newWeather!)               

                })
        }
    }
```

AppDeleage.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let weatherStore = WeatherStore()

    let weatherController = window!.rootViewController as! WeatherViewController

    weatherController.weatherStore = weatherStore

    return true
}
```

Comment: what this method does?
                    afterWeatherCreated(newWeather!)

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar I probably don't need that method there. But I still don't see a solution for my problem.

Comment: Your network request is asynchronous, so you need to reload your tableView after the data has been fetched. You can add it within the code for your `afterWeatherCreated`closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        weatherStore.createWeather { (fetchedWeather: Weather) in
            self.weatherStore.allWeather.append(fetchedWeather)'
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        let statusNarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height

        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: statusNarHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        tableView.contentInset = insets
        tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Just wondering, should you call reloadData() twice? If yes then why.

Comment: It's not about calling it twice, it's because since it's an async call you have to  reload data when you got your data.